# Working with mshtml in c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, mshtml

Working with mshtml + SHDocVw.InternetExplorer was easy in vb. But I have no idea why it would be almost impossible to do that in c#. It makes no sense when it says cannot declare the object type inside the e.g html document. What I am stuck with is the alternatives to the codes below.

```
IE.Document.getElementByID("ID").value="string"
IE.Document.getElementByID("ID").click()
IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tagname")(index).click()
IE.Document.ParentWindow.Frames(index).Document
             .GetElementsByTagName("tagname")(index).click()
IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tagname")(index).value="string"
IE.Document.ParentWindow.Frames(index).Document
             .GetElementsByTagName("tagname")(index).value="string"
```

(using .net 3.5)

Update: Maybe I should have been more specific. The problem is not the brackets, he problem is that the c# does not allow me to call the methods inside the document property.

Comment: Indexed properties are accessed using square brackets in C#, does that help?

Comment: OK, I can see that you are frustrated.  But, for us to help, you are going to have to elaborate on: 1; your original VB code. 2; what EXACT code produces "cannot declare the object type inside the e.g html document.".  and 3; What do you mean by "What I am stuck with is the alternatives to the codes below"

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast objects to COM Interfaces:

```
var doc = IE.Document;
var element = ((IHTMLDocument3)doc).getElementByID("ID");
```